# Packaging of jar, so and class files into APK

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface, android-d8

**Problem (shaped like a 'V'):**

We having a Java function a() - in a.java (top left of V)

a() calls another local function b() implemented via JNI - b.cpp (bottom of V)

b() creates an instance of java class C via JNI - defined in c.java (top right of V)

Nothing in a.java references c.java directly.

---

a.java ends up in a.class     (.apk project)

b.cpp  ends up in libB.so     (.aar project)

c.java ends up in classes.jar (.aar project)

---

**Question:**

How is this run through with Androids 'd8' tool and positioned in an .apk file?

---

**Solution Requirement:**

Command line (not Android Studio)

Answer (score 0):

Just used classes.jar together with a.class as sources when calling d8.
It seems like d8 just puts everything it gets into the resulting classes.dex file - no reference or usage checking.
libB.so lands in lib/*ABI*/libB.so and things just work.

Oh and NEVER forget to use extern "C" in front of your C/C++ functions or name mangling will prevent JNI to find anything in the library. ;)